# .Net Core, Entity Framework Core not working on Linux server

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I deployed a test console app to a linux server and everything works fine but when the code execute an Entity Framework Core query, I get this message in the console

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

On the other hand, if I run it on Windows, it works fine:

[image: console picture]

Comment: Generally speaking, .NET Core and EF work fine on Linux. A LOT more detail is needed to help you.

Comment: @EricJ. I created a console app which it just getting some data for a database and printing to the console. Before hitting the query , it shows all the logs that I added, but once it hit the Entity framework query then I got the error. When I run the app in Visual Studio it works and when I deployed the app to a Windows box it works as well. It is just Linux (Ubuntu) that is not working. Do you think is a versioning issue ?

Comment: Not sure if you found a solution, but I had the same problem.  Spent a whole day trying different environments and various things.  It turned out to be some issue with the particular instance of mssql I was pointed at, works fine on a different mssql instance I have.  Still a mystery, not a "fix", but just a data point.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by integrated security in the connection string. Try to connect with SQL Server authentication. Please check out [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1390).